# Reduction Formula without Partial Fractions

Tags: integration

Let $n>1$ be an integer and $a \neq 0$ a constant. Prove the reduction formula $$\int \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^n} \, dx = \frac{1}{2a^2(n-1)} \left[ \frac{x}{(x^2+a^2)^{n-1}} + (2n-3) \int \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^{n-1}} \, dx \right].$$
Wanting to prove this ... Having difficulty knowing where to start/how to proceed.

Comment: Applying the trigonometric substitution $ \ x \ = \ a \tan \theta \ , \ dx \ = \ a \sec^2 \theta \ d\theta \ $ ,  the integral becomes $$ \rightarrow \ \ \frac{1}{a^{2n-1}} \int \ \cos^{2n-2}  \theta \ \ d\theta \ \ , $$  which is easier to deal with.

Comment: Reduction formula 'always' involves IBP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you can always prove an indefinite integration formula by differentiating both sides.

Comment: Right. But coming up with the formula in the first place is more important...

Comment: But that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 3):

We proceed by integration by parts. Assume $n>1$ so that $n-1>0$ then we have:

$$\int\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n-1}}dx=\frac{x}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n-1}}+2(n-1)\int\frac{x^{2}}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n}}dx$$

$$=\frac{x}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n-1}}+2(n-1)\int\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n-1}}dx-2(n-1)a^{2}\int\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n}}dx$$

Now rearranging the terms we get:

$$\int\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n}}dx=\frac{1}{2(n-1)a^{2}}\bigg(\frac{x}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n-1}}+(2n-3)\int\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n}}dx\bigg)$$

Comment: How come you start with the exponent n-1 ? should it not be n?

Also, what substitution did you use (for u and dv)?

Comment: I started with $n-1$ because I wanted my resulting formula to match yours. Starting the exponent with $n$ would give the same information. When I integrated by parts I used $dv=1$, $v=x$, $du=\frac{2(n-1)x}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n}}$, and $u=\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n-1}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just 1 more question ... Could you explain how you got from the first line to the second line.

What I mean is that from the first line where did the integral(x^2 / ( x^2 + A^2)^n)dx go?

Comment: You're welcome. I used that $\int\frac{x^{2}}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n}}dx=\int\frac{(x^{2}+a^{2})-a^{2}}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n}}dx=\int\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n-1}}dx-\int\frac{a^{2}}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{n}}dx$.